# Is it possible to change xml layout file while already in an activty

Tags: android, layout, dynamic

Currently I have an app that load most of its data from a database call which is done at startup. Its onCreate method correctly calls the associated xml layout file and once the data appears everything is fine. Until that data is created and sent to the phone parsed and loaded the main screen remains black. It is my first inApp purchase App and I built it from the TrivialDrive Sample file provided by Google. What I would like to do is to load an image then begin the data retrieval routine and then have the normal functionality begin at this point including the prebuilt xml file.

I thought about simply creating a startup activity but wouldn't it do the same thing simply load the image and then go back to black when I hit the new oncreate Method in the normal Activity layout file while the data loads .

I am not sure.

What I would like would be to have a single Activity that would load a layout file (with the image) begin the data retrieval when the App knows the data has been retrieved load the data using the actual xml layout file I currently use

Is this possible or does anyone know how I could accomplish this

One other thing I could try is this dynamically create the layout to show an image and then how would I load the existing layout after the data is retrieved or would I be stuck dynamically creating the entire layout file?

Thanks

Comment: You can call `setContentView` several times...

Comment: why you not using asynctask or handler or thread to come out from black screen??

Answer (score 1):

Create an ImageView iv and set the image you required to that imageview. Then call the setContentView(iv). Later once all your work is done again call the setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout), this solves your issue. setContentView() method can be called many times but make sure that once you change the layout, all its views will also get changed. So you cannot find a view which is in another layout.

Comment: Is this the right syntax
 
 ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.hundred);
 setContentView(iv);

   
     String temp = myCallServer(udid, "udid_get_products", "");
        setContentView(R.layout.intro);

Comment: still fairly new to some of these things